# Playing around with bash, getting syntax errors

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to write a simple bash script, for Linux/Unix class, and I keep getting syntax errors. Even my professor at a quick glance couldn't figure it out.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
pattersoncode:~ austen$ ./bash2
./bash2: line 3: if[ =0 ]: command not found
./bash2: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./bash2: line 4: `then'
pattersoncode:~ austen$
```

Regards,

```
a=6
test $a -eq 6 > b
if[ "$b"="0" ]
then
echo True
else
echo False
fi
```

Comment: Some errors: you need spaces around `[` and `]`. Also, to assign into a variable you need `b=$(test $a -eq 6)`, no the current redirection. Also, indentation would help.

Comment: Bash is very sensitive to whitespace, where things like `[` that may look like just brackets are actually programs (a similar executable to  `test`).

Comment: You need spaces around `=` and `if`: `if [ "$b" = "0" ]`. Your professor clearly doesn't know the shell syntax `:D`.

Comment: Syntax errors every where. `test $a -eq 6 > b` doesn't populate variable `b` it just redirects output of `test` command to a file `b`. Then `if[ "$b"="0" ]` should be `if [ "$b" = "0" ]`

Comment: @anubhava I think you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @RSahu I think the question should be closed instead of being answered...

Comment: @RSahu: Didn't feel like posting an answer since it appeared like a homework/class assignment.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: `[` isn't typically an executable; it's usually a shell built-in command. The effect is the same as if it were an executable, though. (Many systems do have `/bin/[`, but the built-in command usually overrides it.)

Comment: I think the real problem is that you're "playing around". Not that there's anything wrong with that, particularly if you want to explore the ways a script can go wrong, but you might be better of starting with existing working code. Change just one thing at a time and see what effect it has.

Comment: As an aside, the output of `test` is always nothing, so `b` will be empty. You can't compare the contents of a file like you are trying to in the `if` condition anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***WHITE SPACE IS EXTREMELY IMPORTANT IN BASH.***

Sorry for the shouting, but this needs to be emphasized. Bash is extremely sensitive to white space unlike other scripting languages such as Perl or Python. For example:

### Right:

```
foo="bar"     # No spaces around the equal sign.
```

### Wrong:

```
foo = "bar"   # This is a syntax error because of the spaces around the equal sign
```

### Right:

```
if [ "$foo" = "bar" ]   # You need spaces around the equal sign.
then
    ...
fi
```

### Wrong":

```
if [ "$foo"="bar" ]   # Syntax error: You forgot the spaces around the equal sign.
then
    ...
fi
```

The shell doesn't *interpret* variables. It *interpolates* variables. There's a subtile difference.

Before the shell executes a command, it runs interference. It looks for environment variables and replaces them with their value. (It also removes globs and replaces them with the matching files too).

For example, these are all valid in Perl:

```
if ( $foo == $bar ) {

if($foo==$bar) {

if ($foo== $bar) {
```

That's because Perl *interprets* the line, so it sees `$foo` and `$bar` as variables even if the white space isn't there. Even if `$foo` and `$bar` are empty, there's no issue. Perl understands that you're comparing the value of the variable `$foo` with the value of the variable `$bar`.

However, the shell operates differently, it *interpolates*. Before that `if` statement is executed, the shell *removes* the environment variables and *replaces* them with their values. Then, and only then does the shell execute the `if` statement.

```
if [ $foo = $bar ]
```

Let's assume that `$foo` is blank while `$bar` is set to `banana`:

The shell sees this:

```
if [ $foo = $bar ]
```

and replaces `$foo` and `$bar` with their assigned values:

```
if [ = banana ]
```

That's a syntax error. You're missing the value on the left of the equals sign. In older shell scripts, you'll see something like this:

```
if [ x$foo = x$bar ]
```

In this case, the shell will remove the environment variables and replace them with their values:

```
if [ x = xbanana ]
```

And that's a valid text comparison. Here's another fun fact. Imagine if `$foo` is equal to the string `-f` while `$bar` is empty:

```
if [ $foo = $bar ]
```

will now be *interpolated* as:

```
if [ -f = ]
```

And, that's valid. It's asking if a file named `=` exists.

The way to get around this issue is to always put quote around your variables. This:

```
if [ "$foo" = "$bar" ]
```

would get interpolated as:

```
if [ "-f" = "" ]
```

And that's a valid string comparison.

By the way, you need white space around the `[` because this isn't some syntax thing, it's a command!

Do an `ls /bin/[`, and you'll see that `[` is a Unix command. It's linked to `/bin/test`.

Thus:

```
if [ "$foo" = "$bar" ]
```

is actually the same as:

```
if test "$foo" = "$bar"
```

And, this is why you also need space around the equal sign too. The `=` is a parameter to the `test` command.

Now, look at your errors and see if you can figure out exactly what they mean:

```
./bash2: line 3: if[ =0 ]: command not found
```

Of course, `if[` isn't a command.  You forgot the white space around `[`. Also, `$b` has no value which is why you don't see it there.

One of the neat things you can do is to add `set -xv` to your shell scripts. This will turn on *verbose* and *debugging*. You'll be able to see the command that the shell sees, then see how the shell interpolates that command. This is a great way for catching errors.

By the way, the actual syntax of the `if` command is:

```
if command
```

The `if` statement runs the command. If the command returns an exit code of zero, the statement is considered true, and thus the `then` portion of the `if` is executed. This is what `[ ... ]` does. (Remember, I said `[` is a command). The `[ ... ]` test is executed. If it's true, then the `then` portion of your `if` statement executes. Otherwise, the `else` clause (if it exists).

You'll see things like this in shell scripts all the time:

```
if ! rm  "$foo"
then
    echo "File '$foo' was removed."
else
    echo "Can't remove file '$foo'."
fi
```

Note I'm merely running `rm` and I'm using `if` to test whether the `rm` command succeeded or not.

Sorry about the wordy explanation. Shell is not a normal scripting language and it can be difficult to understand what's going on unless you understand how the shell operates. Use `set -xv` to turn on debugging and `set +xv` to turn it off.

Also for fun try these two statements and see what happens:

```
$ echo *   # No quotes
$ echo "*" # Quotes around the asterisk
```

Comment: Nice nice nice. BTW _Do an ls /bin/[, and you'll see that [ is a Unix command. It's linked to /bin/test._ Not always is linked to test. With `type [` my system answers `[ is a shell builtin`, and I cannot find in `/bin`. Nevertheless it remains a command. :)

Comment: Yes, in all modern shells, `test` and `[` are _builtin_ much like `echo`, `getopts`, and `pwd` now are. It's to speed up execution. I'm surprised to find out that RHEL, they're `/usr/bin/test` and `/usr/bin/[` and aren't symbolically linked. However, do `/usr/bin/[ --help`, and you can see that the OS considers them one of the same. Still on Mac, they're `/bin/[` and `/bin/test` and hard linked.

Comment: On Ubuntu I find in `/bin` only _the executable files "double" of the builtin commnad_  for `echo,false,kill,pwd,true` (found via `ls /bin/ | awk '{print "type "$1}' | sh | grep builtin`). I remember that it exists the _"double"_ of printf too, so I searched and in `/usr/bin` __I find__ `printf,test` and `__[__`. So `[` was only in a different place, but as in RHEL, is executable and not an hard link (checked with `ls -i` and `md5sum` it gives different inode and different MD5 checksums).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many different ways. This is only one:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=6
test  $a -eq 6
b=$?                # Here you store the error exit code
if [ "$b" = "0" ]
  then
    echo True
  else
    echo False
fi

### short and cryptic bash version  :-) 
aa=7
test  $aa -eq 7  && echo True2 || echo False
```

In `bash` is possible to write in a short way the construct

```
 if test_condition
   then   
       ...   
   else  
       ...  
   fi
```

with
`test_condition && ... || ...`

in which `&&` plays the role of `then` and `||` plays the role of `else`.

Comment: Why not go all the way with `test $(test $(test $(test ...)))` in infinite recursion...?

Comment: @triplee Young mind are like blackboards. That this one was searching a _ready to eat solution_ or to learn by searching deep, it will find its way. BTW, I experienced that to show a ready solution and stimulate with a different way can act on some  as a long and detailed explanation can act on others...